# Android UI: when can I directly modify a view?

Tags: android, ui-thread

I have an app with two activities. From the main activity I start a secondary activity using `startActivityForResult()`. The secondary activity returns data (in the form of an `Intent` object) to the main activity. On the main activity I have a method `onActivityResult()` to handle the come back from the secondary activity.

Within this `onActivityResult()` method, I need to update a `View` on the main activity (to reflect the new data values). I do not explicitly spawn any threads. My question is: can I directly modify the view from within `onActivityResult()` method, or do I need to put an event on the UI queue to do it? To be more explicit: can I be sure that the `onActivityResult()` method is on the UI thread, and in that case can I forget about the UI queue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Yes, you can modify the view in `onActivityResult()`. You can modify an `Activity`'s views anytime after you call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`, as long as you are running on the UI thread.
2. Yes, `onActivityResult()` is called on the UI thread. This is true for all life cycle methods (`onCreate()`, `onResume()`, etc).

Answer (score 13):

Although `onActivityResult` is on Ui thread, you may not see your UI updated when modified in `onActivityResult`. I suspect the reason is redrawing of Ui elements at `onResume` which forces ui elements to reset by calling `resetViews()` of `ActivityTransitionState` at `super.onResume()`.

I faced with this issue while simply updating an `EditText` inside `onActivityResult`. `EditText` was not updated.

The workaround is to save your data in `onActivityResult` and update Ui at `onResume` by setting a flag in `onActivityResult`.

Comment: I just had a lovely hour of hell. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks alot i was trying to Update my views in onActivityResult but this answer really help me thaks alot

Answer (score 3):

The onActivityResult() is executed in the UI thread, you can modify the view on this method.

Comment: Thank you! And after modifying the view, do I need to call `invalidate()`? I'm a bit confused as to when invalidate() needs to be called

Answer (score 0):

When I try to create and show an AlertDialog on onActivityResult() coming back from making a photo, I get an "android.view.WindowLeaked" error
android.view.WindowLeaked:

Activity com...MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{37ac7e30 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-1272,584} that was originally added here

as soon as I try to show the dialog.

So I believe it's not always OK to assume that OnActivityResult() runs on the main thread.