# Update UI from fragment

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

I have a fragment that gets data from a DialogFragment via intent with onActivityResult(...);

I am trying to update the fragment's UI but runOnUiThread does not work.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ArrayList<Farm> farms = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("farms_list");
    float totalArea = 0;
    for(Farm farm : farms) {
        if (farm.isSelected()) {
            Log.d("farm", farm.getName());
            totalArea += farm.getArea();
        }
    }
    final float finalTotalArea = totalArea;
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            area.setText(String.valueOf(finalTotalArea));
        }
    });
}
```

The area TextView does not update.

I get the reference to the activity with onAttach() method.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (!(context instanceof PageFragmentCallbacks)) {
        throw new ClassCastException(
                "Activity must implement PageFragmentCallbacks");
    }

    mCallbacks = (PageFragmentCallbacks) context;
    this.activity = (Activity) context;
}
```

Comment: You should use `getActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {`.

Comment: getActivity() returns null

Comment: When you say that runOnUiThread() doesn't work do you mean that it causes error or that it doesn't process anything?

Comment: It does not render anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425146/runonuithread-in-fragment

Comment: I made a check by calling the isAdded method. It returns false

Comment: Why do you need to use Activity.runOnUIThread(). OnActivityResult is run on the Ui thread already. Btw, is area a TextView of the Activity?

Comment: no area TextView is at the fragment's layout. Also i tried your approach but still the update is not being rendered

Comment: use android handler and post your runnable it´s automatically on the main thread http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 0):

onActivityResult is being called on main thread. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774176/android-ui-when-can-i-directly-modify-a-view). For some reason views can't be edited from this method (probably not created or drawn).
One trick that you can do is set var boolean updateTextView = false;
On onActivityResult set it on true, save data that you got, and than onResume check updateTextView and if true set data to your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to wrap it in a proper thread that you launch afterwards?

```
new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                   activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                          area.setText(String.valueOf(finalTotalArea));
                       }
                   });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `Activity` is loosing your `Fragment` somewhere, what I did in this case was to add a Method to my `Callbacks`, maybe `reattachDialog(DialogFragment dialogFragment)` and calling it in onResume of the DialogFragment with `reattachDialog(this)`.

And in your Activity you do this:

```
@Override
public void reattachFragment(DialogFragment dialogFragment) {
 this.dialogFragment = dialogFragment;
}
```

Or in Fragment:

```
@Override
public void reattachFragment(DialogFragment dialogFragment) {
 getActivity().setDialog(dialogFragment);
}
```